# How to make jquery click() work with css button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click

I have a .button made in css and added to the html 4 times like this

```
<a class="button icon Call"   id="nupp2" href="#"><span>CALL</span></a>
```

and a .js with the following inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("nupp2").click(function(){
      var name=prompt("Please enter your name","blabla");
  });
});
```

The buttons appear if I open the html with firefox and they change if I hover over them 
But if I press the button, it doesn't do anything. I didn't forget to point to the files in the html file.

Am I even doing this right? Or is jquery more complex than I think?

Comment: You need to use a **unique** `id` value for each button... otherwise use a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selectors in jQuery work a lot like the ones in CSS. `$("nupp2")` becomes `$("#nupp2")`, see?

Comment: and if the OP would like to call it by the classname, just use `$(".classNameHere")`

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
$("nupp2").click(function(){
```

The correct is:

```
$("#nupp2").click(function(){
```

The string inside the parens is a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Since you want to select an element by id, the proper selector is a hash sign followed by the id.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a hash sign (#) before the ID of the element - $('#npp')

Answer (score 1):

You missed the hash on your selector:

```
$("#nupp2").click(function(){        // <----- #nupp2
    var name=prompt("Please enter your name","blabla");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To call an ID you need to add a # in front of the selector (Like CSS)

So your jQuery selector should be `$("#nupp2")`

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nupp2").click(function(){
      var name=prompt("Please enter your name","blabla");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(a#nupp).click(function(){
      var name=prompt("Please enter your name","blabla");
  });
});
```